# Issue while sending email in MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I create a sample Empty website in MVC 4.0

I created a Email Folder in Shared Folder and then I added ew Email Templates(email.html.cshtml)

I used MailerBase.

When I tried to send Email, I got runtime error

**The view at '~/Views/Shared/Email/HomeEmail.html.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage.**

To fix this: I added code below on the top of Email template

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
```

Still same issue is coming

Comment: Did you mean "MailerBase", as in ActionMailer.net?

Comment: Rename the view to `EmailSender` or something else, unique. You could have probably hit another class with the same name in the context and the compiler gets confused. I would post this as an answer but there's a chance that it is not the real issue (however, most probably it is).

Comment: Not worked after renaming it.

Comment: How about cleaning up the project?

Comment: I have done cleaning and restarted the machine. Still same

Answer (score 0):

When I create a Internet Application, it started to work. When I created empty application. It does not work. This is the latest finding.

I will remove this answer whenever somebody share the root cause of this issue

Thank You

Comment: Have you done a side by side comparison of the View web.config and main app web.config between the empty application and internet application?

Answer (score 0):

when you create the empty application, 
may be you forgot adding the **web.config file in views folder**.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

 <configuration>
 <configSections>
 <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
   <section name="pages"  type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
 <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
 <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="...YourAppNameSpace..." />
   </namespaces>
 </pages>
 </system.web.webPages.razor>

 <appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
 </appSettings>

 <system.webServer>
  <handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Nope. This is not the reason. I got the ready made config at the time of Empty App.